# Why am I not able to access an attribute from an inherited class?

Tags: python

Given the following classes:

```
class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(CONN_STRING, pool_size=95, max_overflow=0)
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()


class DataAccessLayerParallel(DataAccessLayer):

    def __init__(self):
        session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.connection)
```

I try to create an instance of `DataAccessLayerParallel` as follows:

```
dal = DataAccessLayerParallel()
```

However, I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'DataAccessLayerNonParallel' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

I assume this is because the `__init__` method from `DataAccessLayer` does not run when it is inherited? How would I ensure I can get access to the `connection` attribute?

Comment: In Python, the parent's constructor isn't called automatically; you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the parent constructor with `super`.
Like so:

```py
class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(CONN_STRING, pool_size=95, max_overflow=0)
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()


class DataAccessLayerParallel(DataAccessLayer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DataAccessLayerParallel, self).__init__()
        self.session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.connection)
```

Comment: That code will still raise the same error.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry. I had a small error. Please check the updated answer

Comment: @ekhumoro You need to call the parent constructor before using `self.connection`

Comment: This didn't work for me - used `DataAccessLayer.__init__(self)` instead of `super`

Comment: Another typo! Sorry. I coppied your code, and didn't notice you didn't use `self` when assigning  `session_factory`. Check the answer

Comment: You should use `super`

Comment: No need to write so much code. `super().__init__()` should be enough.

Comment: @Matthias. The other part is not required. But any form of `super` should be used.

Comment: @DiogoSilva Calling the parent class `__init__` directly is perfectly fine when multiple inheritance isn't being used. However, `super().__init__()` is more convenient, because you don't have to repeat the class name. It won't work in Python2, though.